# Cordova: Upload file to an external Drupal site

Tags: drupal, file-upload, cordova

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is the following:

I currently have Cordova loading a page from my external Drupal site. The webpage loads fine, looks great on the screen, the only problem is that it won't allow me to upload a file to through the app itself.

I tried opening the same page in my Android's web browser (Dolphin) and the link worked just fine.

Any help would be appreciated, even if you tell me its not possible, that way I can stop looking and try out another option.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you would need to allow Cordova to write to the server the drupal site is on, which would not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use  the FileTransfer object: 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer